# Does $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}||x(t)-x_e||=0$ imply $||x(t)-x_e||<\epsilon$ for $t\geq T$

Tags: analysis, limits

Does $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}||x(t)-x_e||=0$ imply $\exists T\in\mathbb{R} $  such that $\forall \epsilon>0,t\geq T, ||x(t)-x_e||<\epsilon$ (Continuous case of limit definition?) Assume the metric space is complete.

Normal definition for limit:

$\exists N\in\mathbb{N} $  such that $\forall \epsilon>0,n\geq N, ||x_n-x_e||<\epsilon$

Comment: Do you know the definition of limit? Could you please write it on your post?

Comment: Dear @Cancan, it seem to me that your definition of limit is wrong. To say that $$\lim_{t\to 0}\|x(t)-x_e\|=0$$ is to say that given any $\epsilon>0$, there is $T\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\|x(t)-x_e\|\leq\epsilon $ for $t\geq T$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write that $\forall ε>0 ,\exists T>0$ ,because first you get the $ε$ and then you find a suitable $T=T(ε)$.

Now if we correct this we have that $\forall ε>0,\exists T>0:\|x(t)-x_e\|<ε$ for all $t\geq T$.

or  $\forall ε>0,\exists n\in \Bbb N :\|x(t)-x_e\|<ε$ for all $t\geq n$.

Also there is no problem that we work with real number and not specificaly with naturals because for every real number there is a bigger natural number,so these two definitions are the same.

Also there is no Continuous case of limit definition.